# ViewController memory management （programmatically or using ib）

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, viewcontroller

I'm using Instruments to monitor my app's(ARC) memory usage, and found out that
When I pop a view controller from navigation view controller stack, its dealloc method is called.
But the memory usage only drops a little...(like 0.6M), and still much highter than before.

So here is the problem. The memory usage of my app keeps increasing....

How could I decrease the memory cost to the value before the view controller allocation.
Or at lease how could I release more memory.

Also, it seems that the memory cost is much highter when using xib(storyboard).

Should I set the data to nil like someArr = nil in dealloc method?
I have no idea. Anyone help please! Thank you!!

[This image is captured when one view controller is allocated, and still alive after its dealloc method is called.......](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0a0z.png)

Comment: In the view controller, there maybe some resources cached by system like `UIImage` if you load the image using the method `[UIImage imageNamed:@"xxx.png]"`.

Comment: @KudoCC yeah, I konw that. I usually use [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:] for big images, and [UIImage imageNamed:] for small images like button background images. Do I need to point datasources to nil like someArr = nil , I tried that but doesn't make sense.....The memory usage stays high...

Comment: No, you needn't set them to nil. If you are using xib, maybe it will take some memory after the vc is deallocated, system may cache it so that I you create a new vc with the xib, it will be more faster than loading it from file.

Comment: @KudoCC the memory grows another 7M next I push the vc in navigation controller. It seems that all those vcs(already called dealloc method) are still in memory... If I use a global vc, and every time push the same controller into navigation ctl, the memory seems grow only a little. That's weird...

Comment: It's weird. If you are in a complex project, you can try to write a demo to simulate the context and analyze the demo. If it recur, you can upload it, we can take a look together.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `@autoreleasepool{ }` blocks, though be aware that the memory footprint doesn't necessarily return all the way to where it started.  A big caveat is that if `dealloc` is already called, using autoreleasepool in your code might do nothing because the VC was already released properly.

Though you can consider where to use it *within* the view controller implementation, perhaps within a `dealloc` implementation for the VC.  To ensure that when the VC's dealloc is called, objects that receive an autorelease within the @autoreleasepool block will be released immediately.

Snippet of mine from OSX code:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        // End KVO
        [self stopObservingIndexPath];

        for (NSView* subView in _treeSubViews)
            [subView removeFromSuperview];

        [_categoryView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];

        _treeSubViews = nil;
        _categoryView = nil;
    }
}
```

... that was written in a quest to reduce footprint like yours, by forcibly dismantling the view hierarchy.

And [the Apple reference here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html)

Comment: I think I can understand, but it doesn't work...So far I could see that if I use global var instead, the memory only grows a little, or the memory grows every time I push a vc into navigation controller, and drops to original point after the app becomes active from background.

Comment: If dealloc is called, nothing has retained the VC, and its memory *can* be let go, but might not be immediately. The VC isn't in memory, but its pages are still owned by the app.  The idea above with nil-ing properties in an autorelease block within dealloc is to try to force the app into immediately giving up memory.

Comment: Also make sure you're [not using zombies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html): "Tip: The Zombies template causes memory growth because, to be able to provide information on any zombies, objects’ memory allocations are never really deallocated. So for iOS apps, use it with iOS Simulator rather than on the device itself. For the same reason, don’t use the Zombies template concurrently with the Leaks instrument."